# Upload private key to rundeck key storage

Tags: rundeck

I am trying to upload private key to rundeck key storage, it works with with UI, i want to try this same from REST, any suggestion around this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the new CLI tool. See https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/

The usage is as follows

```
rd keys create help
Create a new key entry.

Usage: create options PATH
    [--file -f value] : File path for reading the upload contents.
    [--path -p value] : Storage path, default: keys/
    [--prompt -p] : (password type only) prompt on console for the password value, if -f is not specified.
    --type -t value : Type of key to store: publicKey,privateKey,password.
```

For example:

```
rd keys create --file id_rsa --path keys/myuser/id_rsa --type privateKey
```